# Compiling matrix multiplication using a list of matrices

Tags: functions, matrix, compile

I'm trying to create compiled function which computes a list of Gamma matrices named `GammaM` and multiply them within the compiled code.

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
Module[{M, GammaM},
M = Table[0.0 + 0.0 I, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
GammaM = Table[gamma[i, n], {i, 1, n}];
M = GammaM[[1]].GammaM[[2]];
M],
CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

However I am unable to get a compiled function; the error I get is:

> Compile::cplist: GammaM[[1]] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
>
> Compile::cset: "Variable M of type !({\"_Complex\", 2}) encountered in assignment of type {!(\"_Integer\", 0)}."

The function `gamma[i,n]` is defined recursively and returns a complex matrix:

```
s3 = {{1.0, 0}, {0.0, -1.0}};
s2 = {{0.0, -I}, {I, 0.0}};
s1 = {{0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0}};
gamma[mu_, N_] :=
 If[mu <= N - 2,
  -KroneckerProduct[gamma[mu, N - 2] , s3],
  If[mu == N - 1, KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2^((N - 2)/2)], s2],
    KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2^((N - 2)/2)], s1]]
  ]
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think `Compile` is the way to go here. Before you even get to the problems with different types, `KroneckerProduct` [isn't compilable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions).

Comment: @blochwave: Thanks for your comment, it indeed works if I define GammaM outside the `Compile` command. However if I replace `GammaM = Table[gamma[i,n], {i,1,n}]` by `GammaM = Table[SparseArray[gamma[i,n]], {i,1,n}]`, it doesn't work and I get back the same errors. I want to make them sparse in order to speed up the computations (which indeed are sped up by defining them as sparse even without the compiled function).

Comment: I think what @blochwave wanted to say is that you won't get a speedup from compiling. `gamma` cannot be compiled (at least not in the current form), and the matrix multiplication will not see any speedup.

Comment: @sebhofer: I thought if I kept the GammaM construction outside the compiled function, then the compiled function will simply take in the stored GammaM matrices from memory. In which case it wouldn't matter if `KroneckerDelta` is compilable or not, because it is called outside `Compile`. Or do I misunderstand the working?

Comment: In some sense you are correct; however by doing this naively you will most likely loose performance as you generate calls to the Mathematica kernel. This could be worked around (e.g. by inlining the definitions of `GammaM` using `With`). But even then I expect no speedup. Where should it come from? The matrix multiplication will certainly be not any faster just because you wrap it in compile.

Comment: Since the gamma matrices are very sparse, make sure everything is sparse. Don't use compilation. Don't declare `M` ahead of time the way you are now, with Table. And make `s1`/`s2`/`s3` sparse, so that the kronecker products also stay sparse. Finally, Consider using memoization (e.g. `gamma[mu_,N_] := gamma[mu,N] = If[....]`) for the `gamma` matrices, as otherwise that recursive call could be nasty. That is, if you have the memory available for memoization.